# difference between numpy dot() and inner()

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

What is the difference between

```
import numpy as np
np.dot(a,b)
```

and

```
import numpy as np
np.inner(a,b)
```

all examples I tried returned the same result. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) has the same article for both?! In [the description](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.inner.html) of `inner()` it says, that its behavior is different in higher dimensions, but I couldn't produce any different output. Which one should I use?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

[`numpy.dot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html#numpy.dot):

> For 2-D arrays it is equivalent to matrix multiplication, and for 1-D arrays to inner product of vectors (without complex conjugation). For N dimensions it is a sum product over the **last axis** of a and the **second-to-last** of b:

[`numpy.inner`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.inner.html):

> Ordinary inner product of vectors for 1-D arrays (without complex conjugation), in higher dimensions a sum product over the **last axes**.

(Emphasis mine.)

As an example, consider this example with 2D arrays:

```
>>> a=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
>>> b=np.array([[11,12],[13,14]])
>>> np.dot(a,b)
array([[37, 40],
       [85, 92]])
>>> np.inner(a,b)
array([[35, 41],
       [81, 95]])
```

Thus, the one you should use is the one that gives the correct behaviour for your application.

---

**Performance testing**

(Note that I am testing only the 1D case, since that is the only situation where `.dot` and `.inner` give the same result.)

```
>>> import timeit
>>> setup = 'import numpy as np; a=np.random.random(1000); b = np.random.random(1000)'

>>> [timeit.timeit('np.dot(a,b)',setup,number=1000000) for _ in range(3)]
[2.6920320987701416, 2.676928997039795, 2.633111000061035]

>>> [timeit.timeit('np.inner(a,b)',setup,number=1000000) for _ in range(3)]
[2.588860034942627, 2.5845699310302734, 2.6556360721588135]
```

So maybe `.inner` is faster, but my machine is fairly loaded at the moment, so the timings are not consistent nor are they necessarily very accurate.

Comment: @MillaWell, they are different even for 2D arrays: they are only the same in 1D. I don't know any performance difference, there are two ways of testing this: [reading the source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/blasdot/_dotblas.c) (not easy) or doing some profiling with `timeit` (much easier).

Comment: I think in general I understood everything. For instance in your example you compute the `.dot`'s first value as (1*11+2*13). How would you compute the `.inner`'s first value of your example?

Comment: @MillaWell, you are correct. Let `c = np.dot(a,b)` and `d = np.inner(a,b)` then `c[i,j] == sum(a[i,:] * b[:,j])` and `d[i,j] == sum(a[i,:] * b[j,:])`.

Comment: Another way of expressing the difference would be to say that they're the same for vectors, but for 2-d arrays, `np.dot(a, b) == np.inner(a, b.T)` and `np.dot(a, b.T) == np.inner(a, b)`.

Answer (score 22):

`np.dot` and `np.inner` are identical for 1-dimensions arrays, so that is probably why you aren't noticing any differences. For N-dimension arrays, they correspond to common tensor operations.

`np.inner` is sometimes called a "vector product" between a higher and lower order tensor, particularly a tensor times a vector, and often leads to "tensor contraction". It includes matrix-vector multiplication.

`np.dot` corresponds to a "tensor product", and includes the case mentioned at the bottom of the Wikipedia page. It is generally used for multiplication of two similar tensors to produce a new tensor. It includes matrix-matrix multiplication.

If you're not using tensors, then you don't need to worry about these cases and they behave identically.

Comment: Looks like `np.dot` is now (i.e. in Python 3) matrix multiplication regardless of dimension. So it is different from `np.inner` even for 1-D arrays.

Comment: I am seeing identical results in NumPy 1.13.3 with Python 3.6.3.  What version are you using?  An example would also be good.

Answer (score 15):

For 1 and 2 dimensional arrays numpy.inner works as transpose the second matrix then multiply.
So for:

```
A = [[a1,b1],[c1,d1]]
B = [[a2,b2],[c2,d2]]
numpy.inner(A,B)
array([[a1*a2 + b1*b2, a1*c2 + b1*d2],
       [c1*a2 + d1*b2, c1*c2 + d1*d2])
```

I worked this out using examples like:

```
A=[[1  ,10], [100,1000]]
B=[[1,2], [3,4]]
numpy.inner(A,B)
array([[  21,   43],
       [2100, 4300]])
```

This also explains the behaviour in one dimension, `numpy.inner([a,b],[c,b]) = ac+bd` and `numpy.inner([[a],[b]], [[c],[d]]) = [[ac,ad],[bc,bd]]`.
This is the extent of my knowledge, no idea what it does for higher dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

inner is not working properly with complex 2D arrays, Try to multiply

and its transpose

```
array([[ 1.+1.j,  4.+4.j,  7.+7.j],
       [ 2.+2.j,  5.+5.j,  8.+8.j],
       [ 3.+3.j,  6.+6.j,  9.+9.j]])
```

you will get

```
array([[ 0. +60.j,  0. +72.j,  0. +84.j],
       [ 0.+132.j,  0.+162.j,  0.+192.j],
       [ 0.+204.j,  0.+252.j,  0.+300.j]])
```

effectively multiplying the rows to rows rather than rows to columns

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot difference between inner product and dot product in higher dimensional space. below is an example of a 2x2 matrix and 3x2 matrix
x = [[a1,b1],[c1,d1]]
y= [[a2,b2].[c2,d2],[e2,f2]

np.inner(x,y)

output = [[a1xa2+b1xb2 ,a1xc2+b1xd2, a1xe2+b1f2],[c1xa2+d1xb2, c1xc2+d1xd2, c1xe2+d1xf2]]

But in the case of dot product the output shows the below error as you cannot multiply a 2x2 matrix with a 3x2.

ValueError: shapes (2,2) and (3,2) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)

Answer (score -1):

I made a quick script to practice inner and dot product math. It really helped me get a feel for the difference:

[image]

You can find the code here:

https://github.com/geofflangenderfer/practice_inner_dot

Comment: any explanation for down vote? This helped me and I think it will help others as well.

Comment: Can you please include the basic code in the answer.