# numpy matrix vector multiplication

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector, matrix

When I multiply two `numpy` arrays of sizes (n x n)*(n x 1), I get a matrix of size (n x n). Following normal matrix multiplication rules, an (n x 1) vector is expected, but I simply cannot find any information about how this is done in Python's Numpy module.

The thing is that I don't want to implement it manually to preserve the speed of the program.

Example code is shown below:

```
a = np.array([[5, 1, 3], [1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1]])
b = np.array([1, 2, 3])

print a*b
   >>
   [[5 2 9]
   [1 2 3]
   [1 4 3]]
```

What I want is:

```
print a*b
   >>
   [16 6 8]
```

Answer (score 462, accepted):

### Simplest solution

Use `numpy.dot` or `a.dot(b)`. See the documentation [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html).

```
>>> a = np.array([[ 5, 1 ,3], 
                  [ 1, 1 ,1], 
                  [ 1, 2 ,1]])
>>> b = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> print a.dot(b)
array([16, 6, 8])
```

This occurs because numpy arrays are not matrices, and the standard operations `*, +, -, /` work element-wise on arrays.

Note that while you can use [`numpy.matrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) (as of early 2021) where `*` will be treated like standard matrix multiplication, ***`numpy.matrix` is deprecated and may be removed in future releases.***. See [the note in its documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) (reproduced below):

> It is no longer recommended to use this class, even for linear algebra. Instead use regular arrays. The class may be removed in the future.

*Thanks @HopeKing.*

---

### Other Solutions

Also know there are other options:

- As noted below, if using python3.5+ and numpy v1.10+, the `@` operator works as you'd expect:

  ```
  >>> print(a @ b)
  array([16, 6, 8])
  ```
- If you want overkill, you can use [`numpy.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html#numpy.einsum).  The documentation will give you a flavor for how it works, but honestly, I didn't fully understand how to use it until reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33641428/1634191) and just playing around with it on my own.

  ```
  >>> np.einsum('ji,i->j', a, b)
  array([16, 6, 8])
  ```
- As of mid 2016 (numpy 1.10.1), you can try the experimental [`numpy.matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html#numpy-matmul), which works like `numpy.dot` with two major exceptions: no scalar multiplication but it works with stacks of matrices.

  ```
  >>> np.matmul(a, b)
  array([16, 6, 8])
  ```
- [`numpy.inner`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.inner.html) functions the same way as `numpy.dot` **for matrix-vector multiplication but behaves differently** for matrix-matrix and tensor multiplication (see Wikipedia regarding the differences between [the inner product and dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) in general or [see this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033573/difference-between-numpy-dot-and-inner) regarding numpy's implementations).

  ```
  >>> np.inner(a, b)
  array([16, 6, 8])

  # Beware using for matrix-matrix multiplication though!
  >>> b = a.T
  >>> np.dot(a, b)
  array([[35,  9, 10],
         [ 9,  3,  4],
         [10,  4,  6]])
  >>> np.inner(a, b) 
  array([[29, 12, 19],
         [ 7,  4,  5],
         [ 8,  5,  6]])
  ```
- If you have multiple ***2D arrays*** to `dot` together, you may consider the  [`np.linalg.multi_dot`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.multi_dot.html#numpy.linalg.multi_dot) function, which simplifies the syntax of many nested `np.dot`s.  Note that this only works with 2D arrays (i.e. not for matrix-vector multiplication).

  ```
    >>> np.dot(np.dot(a, a.T), a).dot(a.T)
    array([[1406,  382,  446],
           [ 382,  106,  126],
           [ 446,  126,  152]])
    >>> np.linalg.multi_dot((a, a.T, a, a.T))
    array([[1406,  382,  446],
           [ 382,  106,  126],
           [ 446,  126,  152]])
  ```

---

### Rarer options for edge cases

- If you have tensors (arrays of dimension greater than or equal to one), you can use [`numpy.tensordot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html#numpy.tensordot) with the optional argument `axes=1`:

  ```
  >>> np.tensordot(a, b, axes=1)
  array([16,  6,  8])
  ```
- **Don't use [`numpy.vdot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vdot.html#numpy.vdot)** if you have a matrix of complex numbers, as the matrix will be flattened to a 1D array, then it will try to find the complex conjugate dot product between your flattened matrix and vector (which will fail due to a size mismatch `n*m` vs `n`).

Comment: IMP note: numpy matrices are to be avoided in favor of arrays. Note from documentation --> "It is no longer recommended to use this class, even for linear algebra. Instead use regular arrays. The class may be removed in the future." See also stackoverflow.com/a/61156350/6043669

Comment: Excellent answer wflynny

Comment: You might be able to give a better answer than me here: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/8474/5