# Trouble Multiplying Columns of a Numpy Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am trying to multiply columns of a numpy matrix together. I have followed the code given in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21562986/numpy-matrix-vector-multiplication).

Here is what the column looks like:

[image]

Here is what happens when I try to multiply two columns of the matrix together.

[image]

Maybe the issue is that the column is stored differently? Some of the printouts in the other questions do not have the numbers stored in separate lists.

Comment: How do you define  `new_train_data`? It doesn't look as a vanilla 2D array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[With `np.matrix`, the `*` operator does matrix multiplication](https://web.archive.org/web/20150818181140/http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users#head-e9a492daa18afcd86e84e07cd2824a9b1b651935) rather than element-wise multiplication, which is what I assume you're trying to do.

You get a `ValueError` because the two column vectors are not properly aligned for matrix multiplication. Their inner dimensions don't match, since their shapes are `(N, 1)` and `(N, 1)` respectively. They would need to be either `(1, N)`, `(N, 1)` (for the inner product) or `(N, 1)`, `(1, N)` (for the outer product) in order for matrix multiplication to work.

If you choose to stick to using `np.matrix` to hold your data, you could use the [`np.multiply()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html) function to do element-wise multiplication:

```
result = np.multiply(new_train_data[:, 0], new_train_data[:, 1])
```

However, I would recommend that you use `np.array` instead of `np.matrix` in future. With `np.array` the `*` operator does element-wise multiplication, and the `np.dot()` function (or the `.dot()` method of the array) does matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

`new_train_data` is evidently a `matrix` (subclass of `ndarray`).  Its `*` is defined as matrix multiplication (like the `np.dot`), not the element by element multiplication of regular numpy arrays.  Hence the 'alignment' error message.

Answer (score -2):

Well in the answer it uses numpy.dot to multiply n*n with n...works for me!