# Linear algebra in Numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am working on matrix multiplications in NumPy using np.dot(). As the data set is very large, I would like to reduce the overall run time as far as possible - i.e. perform as little as possible np.dot() products.

Specifically, I need to calculate the overall matrix product as well as the associated flow from each element of my values vector.
Is there a way in NumPy to calculate all of this together in one or two np.dot() products? 
In the code below, is there a way to reduce the number of np.dot() products and still get the same output?

---

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

vector = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3],
                      ['A', 'B', 'C'], ["Values"])

matrix = pd.DataFrame([[0.5, 0.4, 0.1],
                       [0.2, 0.6, 0.2],
                       [0.1, 0.3, 0.6]],
                      index = ['A', 'B', 'C'], columns = ['A', 'B', 'C'])

# Can the number of matrix multiplications in this part be reduced?
overall = np.dot(vector.T, matrix)
from_A = np.dot(vector.T * [1,0,0], matrix)
from_B = np.dot(vector.T * [0,1,0], matrix)
from_C = np.dot(vector.T * [0,0,1], matrix)

print("Overall:", overall)
print("From A:", from_A)
print("From B:", from_B)
print("From C:", from_C)
```

Comment: See the discussion here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21562986/numpy-matrix-vector-multiplication

Comment: Can you provide a better example of a desired input and output? It's not clear exactly what you want.

Comment: You don't need a matrix multiplication at all here. See my answer. I think it is better than the currently selected one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a `3 x 3` shaped `2D` array of those scaling values and perform matrix-multiplication, like so -

```
scale = np.array([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])
from_ABC = np.dot(vector.values.ravel()*scale,matrix)
```

Sample run -

```
In [901]: from_A
Out[901]: array([[ 0.5,  0.4,  0.1]])

In [902]: from_B
Out[902]: array([[ 0.9,  1.6,  0.5]])

In [903]: from_C
Out[903]: array([[ 0.8,  1.3,  1.9]])

In [904]: from_ABC
Out[904]: 
array([[ 0.5,  0.4,  0.1],
       [ 0.9,  1.6,  0.5],
       [ 0.8,  1.3,  1.9]])
```

Here's an alternative with [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) to do all those in one step -

```
np.einsum('ij,ji,ik->jk',vector.values,scale,matrix)
```

Sample run -

```
In [915]: np.einsum('ij,ji,ik->jk',vector.values,scale,matrix)
Out[915]: 
array([[ 0.5,  0.4,  0.1],
       [ 0.9,  1.6,  0.5],
       [ 0.8,  1.3,  1.9]])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. This is extremely helpful!

Comment: @Andreas Glad to be of help!

Comment: And `scale` is just `np.eye(3)`

Comment: @kennytm thanks! I was using np.identity(x) before, but now switched to the more general np.eye(x).

Comment: @kennytm Yeah I went with a generic version for the scaling values.

Answer (score 2):

If the vectors you use to select the row are indeed the unit vectors, you are much better off not doing matrix multiplication at all for `from_A`, `from_B`, `from_C`. Matrix multiplication requires a lot more addition and multiplications than you need to just multiply each row of the matrix by it's corresponding entry in the vector:

```
from_ABC = matrix.values * vector.values
```

You will only need a single call to `np.dot` to get `overall`.

Comment: thanks. Very helpful to know that np.dot is much slower than a simple product using *.

Comment: It's just a matter of quantity of operations. My product broadcasts so that there are just matrix.size products and no sums. The dot has vector.size * matrix.size products and matrix.shape[0] sums.

Comment: I just assumed OP had a minimal sample case with the scaling values, but it seems those are the actual values OP is working with. So, this one's good!

Comment: @Divakar. I thought so too at first, but the names `from_A`, etc. made me think that they are just row selectors.