# Python: how to multiply each element in a row and a column without looping

Tags: python

In Python, I have a column array and a row array, say, [1, 3, 5] and [2, 4, 6, 8]' and I want to create a matrix of size 4*3 by multiplying each element in both of them. Is it possible to do without looping?

Comment: Please give an example of the output.

Comment: You can use `numpy` for this. First `import numpy as np` and then I think you're looking for: `np.array([1, 3, 5])*np.array([[2], [4], [6], [8]])`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [numpy matrix vector multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21562986/numpy-matrix-vector-multiplication)

Answer (score 1):

Vectorized calculation are best done with numpy:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(1,6,2) # [1,3,5]
y = np.arange(2,9,2) # [2,4,6,8]
x = np.array([x]) # add dimension for transposing.
y = np.array([y])
result = np.dot(x.T, y)
```

result:

```
array([[ 2,  4,  6,  8],
       [ 6, 12, 18, 24],
       [10, 20, 30, 40]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code

import numpy as np

```
>>> x1 = np.arange(2,9,2)   # [2,4,6,8]
>>> x2 = np.arange(1,6,2)   # [1,3,5]
>>> result = x1.dot(x2)
>>> print result
```

Comment: `ValueError: shapes (4,) and (3,) not aligned: 4 (dim 0) != 3 (dim 0)`