# Multiplying matrices with enumerate

Tags: python, matrix, matrix-multiplication, enumerate

How could I use enumerate to multiply two matrices together in Python?

I know how to do it with numpy and by using range and len, but I really want to use enumerate.

Comment: It might help if you show first how you do it with numpy, and  a few things you tried and did not work.

Comment: Which? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21562986/numpy-matrix-vector-multiplication