# Vectorized matrix multiplication in Python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication

Maybe it's ill advised doing this in the first place, but I'm trying to multiply a (k,k) matrix with (k,1) random vector, and I want to do this M times. I want to do this in one calculation, so having a (k,M) matrix and multiplying each column by my (k,K) matrix. Similar to how you would multiply a scalar with a vector. Is this possible without a loop?

Comment: What's your expected output? Maybe provide an example of sample input and output.

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Also research the available operations in NumPy and other matrix-supporting packages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [numpy matrix vector multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21562986/numpy-matrix-vector-multiplication)

Answer (score 0):

Not in pure Python. The `numpy` package is universally used for numerical computation in Python. It provides several ways of doing this kind of vectorized matrix multiplication, of which the most common is probably `numpy.matmul()`:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html