# How to rotate 3d array with rotation matrix - python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3d numpy array of size `V.shape=(70,70,70)` that I wish to rotate with a specific rotation matrix. My rotation matrix looks like:

```py
M = np.array([[0.60,-0.79,0.04]
             ,[-0.59,-0.40,0.70]
             ,[-0.54,-0.45,-0.71]])
```

How would I go about rotating my volume using that specific rotation matrix?

Comment: I think your question is answered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21562986/numpy-matrix-vector-multiplication)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see that. My problem is that my dimensions don't match in the first place. I would assume the solution would be something akin to using a meshgrid to transform coordinates and then interpolate new positions.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood. I thought your array was [70,70,70] not the shape being 70,70,70. Shoulda been obvious. Sorry.