# Create Matrix in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix-multiplication, multiplication

My question Regarding Python matrix. How to create a python matrix multiplication.

1. For example, multiply 8 * 4 and 4 * 6?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [numpy matrix vector multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21562986/numpy-matrix-vector-multiplication)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between numpy dot() and Python 3.5+ matrix multiplication @](/q/34142485/90527), [how does multiplication differ for NumPy Matrix vs Array classes?](/q/3890621/90527)

Comment: … [Matrix Multiplication in pure Python?](/a/47421436/90527)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `numpy` library by using `matmul(MatrixA,MatrixB)` method.

In this method `matmul` you can pass two arguments "MatrixA" & "MatrixB" and it will multiply both matrixes together

##### Usage

```py
import numpy as np

# Matrix A
A = [[2, 4],
      [6, 8]]

# Matrix B      
B = [[1, 3],
      [5, 7]]
 
"""
It will do the following:
A = [[2,4],[6,8]]
B = [[1,3],[5,7]]

After running the method
C = [[2*1, 4*3],[6*5, 8*7]] = [[2, 12],[30, 56]]
"""
print(np.matmul(A,B))
```

For more Information, you can head to this topic [here](https://www.educative.io/blog/numpy-matrix-multiplication)